# CI default controller showing empty page

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I can't get the default controller to work on my localhost session.

#### routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

#### .htaccess file

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
```

My controller name is `Welcome.php`. visiting `localhost/welcome` doesn't throw any error instead it just shows an empty page.

`Welcome.php` controller:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

My `welcome_message.php` is the default provided by CodeIgniter

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome to CodeIgniter</title>

    <style type="text/css">

    ::selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }
    ::-moz-selection { background-color: #E13300; color: white; }

    body {
        background-color: #fff;
        margin: 40px;
        font: 13px/20px normal Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #4F5155;
    }

    a {
        color: #003399;
        background-color: transparent;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #444;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: normal;
        margin: 0 0 14px 0;
        padding: 14px 15px 10px 15px;
    }

    code {
        font-family: Consolas, Monaco, Courier New, Courier, monospace;
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        color: #002166;
        display: block;
        margin: 14px 0 14px 0;
        padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
    }

    #body {
        margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
    }

    p.footer {
        text-align: right;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        line-height: 32px;
        padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
        margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    }

    #container {
        margin: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
        box-shadow: 0 0 8px #D0D0D0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <h1>Welcome to CodeIgniter!</h1>

    <div id="body">
        <p>The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.</p>

        <p>If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:</p>
        <code>application/views/welcome_message.php</code>

        <p>The corresponding controller for this page is found at:</p>
        <code>application/controllers/Welcome.php</code>

        <p>If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the <a href="user_guide/">User Guide</a>.</p>
    </div>

    <p class="footer">Page rendered in <strong>{elapsed_time}</strong> seconds. <?php echo  (ENVIRONMENT === 'development') ?  'CodeIgniter Version <strong>' . CI_VERSION . '</strong>' : '' ?></p>
</div>

</body>
```

**[EDIT]**: visiting any link `localhost/apple` or `localhost` even when none of the controller `Apple.php` or anything as such is defined, leads me to an empty web page.

**[EDIT 2]**: My `config.py` has

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
```

**[EDIT 3]**: My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
##
# You should look at the following URL's in order to grasp a solid understanding
# of Nginx configuration files in order to fully unleash the power of Nginx.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
# http://wiki.nginx.org/QuickStart
# http://wiki.nginx.org/Configuration
#
# Generally, you will want to move this file somewhere, and start with a clean
# file but keep this around for reference. Or just disable in sites-enabled.
#
# Please see /usr/share/doc/nginx-doc/examples/ for more detailed examples.
##

# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen   80;
    listen   [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
        break;
    }

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
#   location ~ \.php$ {
#       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
#
#       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
#       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#       # With php7.0-fpm:
#       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
#}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# Virtual Host configuration for example.com
#
# You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and symlink that
# to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
#
#server {
#   listen 80;
#   listen [::]:80;
#
#   server_name example.com;
#
#   root /var/www/example.com;
#   index index.html;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

Comment: remove your `.htaccess` and it should works fine

Comment: It still doesn't work after removing both `application/.htaccess` and `system/.htaccess`.

Comment: What Response Code to you get from local server? `200` or `404`? Is the document root folder correct? Also check `.htaccess` from document root folder.

Comment: nginx do NOT support `.htaccess` files. So `.htaccess` is not the problem.

Comment: can you try this way : http://localhost/project_name/index.php/welcome

Comment: Your URL should like `localhost/YOUR_PROJEC_TNAME/` because your default controller is welcome so it's automatically called when you try with localhost and your project name

Comment: @AbhishekDesai my project files are present in `/var/www/html`. So the root directory of my project is `/var/www/html`.

Comment: @rajesh I tried `localhost/index.php/welcome`, but that doesn't work either. Since the root directory of my project is `/var/www/html`, that would be what you imply right?

Comment: @gxyd can you please try with make a new folder and put whole the CI source code in that folder and try to run with `localhost/foldername`

Comment: @Cyborg can you please tell me how do I know what response did I get from my local server? (my web page is blank, so does that remove the possibility of `404`?), I don't see no log entry for request  in `/var/log/nginx/error.log`.

> Is the document root folder correct?

Since all my project files are in `/var/root/html`, isn't it fine?

Also I've made an edit (`EDIT 2`) to my original post, mentioning the value of `base_url`

Comment: need to set $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project_name'

Comment: There is 2 ways to check: 1. In Google Chrome goto `View` -> `Developer` -> `Developer Tools` then reload the URL and you will see `Status Code`.
2. option is goto Terminal/Shell and run CMD Curl with Verbose like: `curl -v 'http://127.0.0.1'`.
You should NOT use `/var/root/html` but use `/var/www/html`.
I think your problem is in Nginx configuration or PHP-FPM configuration.

Comment: project_name  is a name of your project folder

Comment: @Cyborg sorry I meant `/var/www/html`. Now moving my project files to `/var/www/html/foldername`, i.e. the root directory of my project is `/var/www/html/foldername`, I'm getting `404` on visiting `localhost/foldername/index.php/welcome`. 

I've set my `base_url` as `$config['base_url'] = 'localhost/foldername';`, as suggested by @AbhishekDesai and @rajesh

Comment: BTW, I use `sudo service nginx restart` to restart `nginx`, instead of `sudo service nginx restart` as suggested by the articles I've read.

Doing `sudo systemctl nginx restart` I'm getting `Unknown operation nginx.` Could this by any issue?

Comment: Have you checked `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` ? `index.php` is not a folder so `index.php/welciome` will not work.

Comment: Using `ps aux | grep nginx`

```
Using `ps aux | grep nginx` I'm getting:
```
root     29506  0.0  0.0 125124  2324 ?        Ss   17:46   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data 29507  0.0  0.0 125448  3252 ?        S    17:46   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

(removed some of the lines).

Comment: @Cyborg `http://localhost/foldername/welcome` **doesn't** work either.

Comment: Confirm `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` is OK and it should have document root path to: `/var/www/html/foldername` Then make 1 `test.php` file add it in: `/var/www/html/foldername` Then try: `http://127.0.0.1/test.php` or `localhost/test.php`. (From shell Curl `localhost` will not work and only `http://127.0.0.1` will work).

Comment: I've only one file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` and that is `default`. I've already pasted its content in **EDIT 3** in my original post. Should it be `Test.php`, instead of `test.php`?

Comment: I'm getting the status code as `200` now after setting `root /var/www/html/foldername;` in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Comment: After some tinkering I've got the `localhost/foldername` working. My `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` has `root /var/www/html;` it contains

```
    location /foldername {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /foldername/index.php;
    }

 # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
 # concurs with nginx's one
 #
 #location ~ /\.ht {
 # deny all;
 #}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change your CLASS name to Welcome Instead on welcome  (i.e. use capital W)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qU9td.png)

Answer (score 0):

Open you `Welcome.php` controller:

Paste below code as well :

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```